# Expected value sum identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, expectation, direct-sum

Let Y be a random variable taking on values in the non-negative integers.

> Claim: $E\left(Y\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP\left[Y=n\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}P\left[Y=n\right]=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}P\left[Y=n\right]$

The second equality seems to be a change of dummy index.
I do not see how the third equality holds.

Any help is appreciated.

edit:

I tried understanding the above like this, and wondered if it's also valid.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P\left[Y=n \right ] \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(1\right) =P\left[1 \right ]\left ( 1 \right )+ \cdot \cdot \cdot $

so we see that the upper bound term $n$ of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1 \right )$ is dependent on the upper bound term $a$ in$ \lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{a} \left ( 1 \right )= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( 1 \right )$.

Keeping the above in mind, we have $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left ( 1 \right )=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left ( 1 \right )=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left ( 1 \right )$
to give $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P\left[Y=n \right ]$ for the third equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $[k\leq n]$ denote a function that takes value $1$ if indeed $k\leq n$ and that takes value $0$ otherwise.

Then:

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP(Y=n) & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[k\leq n]P(Y=n)\\
 & =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[k\leq n]P\left(Y=n\right)\\
 & =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}P\left(Y=n\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: The piecewise function you define and used in conjunction with the summation is very uncomfortable and difficult to understand.
Can you explain?

Comment: Do you understand that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[k\leq n]=n$? This purely because there are exactly $n$ elements $k$ in $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ that satisfy $k\leq n$. Namely $1,2,\dots,n$.

Comment: Functions like this give the opportunity to eliminate "annoying" indexes. The $k$ and $n$ in my answer start both at $1$ and go to $\infty$.

Comment: I have made an edit to the OP.

Comment: What you write in your edit is 1) wrong 2) hard to follow 3) making things more complicated than they really are. Do you understand my answer?  If so then you are ready. If not then which of the 3 equalities do you not understand?

Comment: I follow the technicalities in your solutions; I would also prefer to understand it on an intuitive level.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$n= \underbrace{1+\cdots +1}_n = \sum_{k=1}^n1$$
Then, sum along the columns instead of the rows in 
$$\begin{pmatrix} P\left[Y=1\right] & & & \cdots \\
P\left[Y=2\right] & P\left[Y=2\right] & & \cdots \\
P\left[Y=3\right] & P\left[Y=3\right] &P\left[Y=3\right] & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots \\
\end{pmatrix}$$